# How to remove all the description of the image, show only title when mouse over on it which we can do it with title attribute in webpages

Tags: image

please help me with my problem, how to display only name instead of all the description of the images when mouse hover by using any softwares or with php. Generally we can do that in html by using title tag, i want exactly same in normal windows image hovering.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is not so clear to me. For example, what do you mean with “in normal windows image hovering”?

Comment: when we keep our cursor on any image we can see its description in any operating system, xp or windows 7 or others. But i want to see only title of that image not even Title: something just its image name as hover description. Thanks for responding.